# Convert function into a nested list comprehension (Python)

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Can anyone convert the below function into a list compressions please!

```
 def something(x,y):

  result = []
  for i in x:
    for j in y:
      if i['username'] == j['username']:
       result.append(j)
    if i['username'] != result[len(result)-1]['username']:
      result.append(i)

  return result
```

This is best I could come up with but it is not correct.

```
result = [user for user in users for contact in contacts if contact['username'] == user['username']]
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does "its not good enough" mean?  *How* is it not good enough?

Comment: It does not give the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what `if i['username'] != result[len(result)-1]['username']: result.append(i)` is really doing is to append `i` when there is nothing in `y` found to match the `username` of `i` (because if there was any match in the `y` loop the last item in `result` would have the same `username` as `i`), you can make the inner loop a sub-list and use the `or` operator to default to `[i]` if the sub-list is empty, and finally use nested list comprehension to flatten the list:

```
result = [a for s in [[j for j in y if i['username'] == j['username']] or [i] for i in x] for a in s]
```

Or if you prefer the variable names in your latter code example:

```
result = [a for s in [[contact for contact in contacts if user['username'] == contact['username']] or [user] for user in users] for a in s]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.